# Batch Query Dell Service Tags for System Configs

Tags: scripting, dell

Not sure if any of the smart folks in this thread [Batch Query Dell Service Tags](https://serverfault.com/questions/67735/batch-query-dell-service-tags) are still around but I have a very similar problem: I need to query the Dell Support website to gather original system configurations, rather than warranty details.

I've tried every modification of the script above that I can think of with no luck.

Anyone? Class? Bueller?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I would propably use curl for this. The problem is that the dell-pages shows a java-popup where you enter the service-tag. But I think this just sets a cookie...

Trace one of your sessions with firebug or some other http-debugging-tool. If you transfer the right parameters and the right cookies it should work.

I think the old python script was run against the dell-site when it used older technology to create the page-contents (perhaps perl?).